# How to divide the dataset when it is distributed

Tags: python, pytorch, distributed

Now I want to divide a dataset into two parts: the train set and validation set. I know that on a single GPU I can do this using a sampler:

```
indices = list(range(len(train_data)))
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
      train_data, batch_size=args.batch_size,
      sampler=torch.utils.data.sampler.SubsetRandomSampler(indices[:split]),
      pin_memory=True, num_workers=2)
```

But when I want to train it in a parallel way using `torch.distributed`, I have to use another sampler, namely, `sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(train_data)`

So how should I do to use the two samplers, so that I can divide the dataset and distribute it at the same time?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split `torch.utils.data.Dataset` before creating `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`.

Simply use [torch.utils.data.random_split](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.random_split) like this:

```
train, validation =
    torch.utils.data.random_split(
        dataset, 
        (len(dataset)-val_length, val_length)
    )
```

This would give you two separate datasets which could be used with dataloaders however you wish.

Comment: @sunshk1227 Mark as solved with green tick if the answer fixed your issue, thanks

Comment: Got it! I am new here. : -)